# How to change the FTP Directory Format in response to a NLIST (AT+NLST) instruction

Tags: linux, ftp, pure-ftpd

I hope someone can help. This is an FTP IOT related question. We are moving a IOT management portal from a web server to a VPS. The VPS is all setup and working but we are getting an incorrect FTP Native response to a PHP NLIST command:

```
/public_ftp/bin9/..
/public_ftp/bin9/.
/public_ftp/bin9/Filename_0,12.bin
```

The original website gave this FTP Standard response to the same command:

```
.
..
Filename_0,12.bin
```

The field devices are programed to parse the file name from this response where the pathnames are not included (second example). Parsing is failing on the new VPS response due to the incorrect FTP Native Directory Format. I have spent many weeks Googling this problem without success. I have also tried many different  Ubunto, Centos, Apache, Nginx, and different FTP server combinations without success. Our VPS is currently setup with Ubunto 16.04, Nginx 1.15 and PureFTP . I cannot find any configuration option that will select the FTP Standard Directory format where the directory path is not included and only file names listed.
    I hope someone out there can help  as I’m now really stuck with this problem.

Comment: What FTP server software did you use on the original server? (And, where does "AT+NLST" come from? FTP doesn't use Hayes AT commands.)

Comment: Why would this be tagged with Apache HTTP if it's about FTP?

Comment: The original website used a PureFTPD server, the iot field devices use a AT+NLST instruction to get the file list from the server. We use a PHP NLIST instruction for testing as the result is exactly the same. The question is tagged Apache HTTP because we now believe this is a Apache server issue.